# How to create an SpringMVC5 app using Netbeans 11.1+GlassFish5?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, netbeans, ant, glassfish

I'm trying for days and days, how to create a simple hello world using **Netbeans 11.1**, with **springmvc 5.0.2 jars** with glassfish5 (standalone and not the netbeans), but I can't because I always get this error:

```
 Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
```

I need to keep using glassfish standalone because in my classroom students don't have administrator permission. **I was able to use JSP and even JSTL, but Spring not**...

So far I have been using the "new web project with ant" option

Comment: You need to improve this question by **explicitly stating the steps you took to create the application**, so that anyone reading it can emulate what you did. Without that information, any responses are just guesses. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further details on how to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up using glassfish and used a new project web with maven and spring-boot-starter-tomcat